# Feathersjs auth conflict on Windows

Tags: node.js, mongoose, feathersjs

After generating an app that has local auth with the `feathers cli` the first user gets created normally but when i try to authenticate with it it gives this error

[image]

then i went ahead and tried to add other users and it responds with `409 conflict` although i change all the information

[image]

this is the mongoose model that am using

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const modelName = "users";
  const mongooseClient = app.get("mongooseClient");
  const schema = new mongooseClient.Schema(
    {
      userName: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
      password: { type: String, required: true },
      displayName: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a windows issue apparently you'll just have to edit escape the name as it is **WRITTEN IN THE OFFICIAL DOCS** 
[image]

I apologize greatly for your time

[image]